# How to disable TextBlock?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want my TextBlock to look disabled (grayed out) but when I set `IsEnabled` property to false nothing happens, it stays black:

```
<TextBlock Text="test" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Why is that?

Also I tried to use `Label` but it's size is bigger for some reason, so it will mess up all my layout.

Comment: Label has a built-in 5px padding. Use <Label Padding="0"> if you want to use it in place of a TextBlock like that.

Comment: Actually that was the answer, will use labels instead.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This would be the proper way to do it with a TextBlock i think:

```
<TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 13):

I played a little and found out that half opacity is giving the same resultat as IsEnabled="False".

```
<TextBlock Text="test" Opacity="0.5" />
```

Advantage : it fits to every Foreground color.

Answer (score 2):

You can play with Background and apply a SystemColor.
Here is an example to get you started.

```
<TextBlock IsEnabled="True" 
        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" 
        Name="textBlock" 
        Text="TEST TextBlock" 
        Height="30" />
```

Your other option is to try the IsReadOnly property of the TextBox.